# How do you split the following vector of strings based on a delimiter that occurs after a certain character pattern in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

Here is an example of the vector:
`strings<- (c("SPG_L_SPG_R", "SAS_SPG_R_SFG_L", "s_cere_R_SPG_L" ))`
I need the split strings to be `"SPG_L", "SPG_R","SAS_SPG_R", "SFG_L", "s_cere_R", "SPG_L"`

I want to split the string at "_" that occurs after either an "_L" or an "_R"

I know there is a way of splitting strings like this using regex and then I want to use an apply function to apply the string splitting function to the entire vector. I have searched the forum for examples to help me do this, but I am still struggling. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [positive look-behind assertion](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#look-arounds), we can split at `_` preceded by R or L

```
stringr::str_split(strings, '(?<=[RL])_', simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]        [,2]   
[1,] "SPG_L"     "SPG_R"
[2,] "SAS_SPG_R" "SFG_L"
[3,] "s_cere_R"  "SPG_L"
```

Comment: Maybe include unlist(str_split(strings,'(?<=[RL])_')) to get in a vector rather than a list.